# Inserting data using JQUERY and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

Imagine I have 3 data's in my `room_table` and the column is `room_id, image, room_name` then I'm going to display the data of my `room_table` in my html code.

PS: Ignore the `text_checkin, text_checkout` first. I'm going to explain after the code.

HTML code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('xxxxxx', 'xxxx', '', 'xxxx');
$rooms = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY id ASC;");

<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rooms)) { ?>
   <div>
    <form >
            <img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" style="width: 20%;">
            <label>Check IN</label>
            <input type="date" name="text_checkin" id="text_checkin">
            <br>
            <label>Check OUT</label>
            <input type="date" name="text_checkout" id="text_checkout">
            <br>
            <label>Room ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="text_roomid" id="text_roomid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return chk()">
            <br><br><br>
    </form>
    <p id="msg"></p>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I have table named `reservation` then the columns are `room_id, checkin, checkout`.

the 3 data's in my `room_table` will display. Then the textbox, and the button will be thrice cause of the `while` loop. Then imagine I clicked the button `submit` in the 2nd row, then the 2nd row `id` should insert on my table `reservation` but the problem is only first row `id` is inserting on table `reservation`

Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chk()
{
var roomid = document.getElementById('text_roomid').value;
var checkin = document.getElementById('text_checkin').value; 
var checkout = document.getElementById('text_checkout').value;
var dataString = 'roomid='+ roomid + '&checkin=' + checkin + '&checkout=' + checkout;
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "server.php",
  data:dataString,
  cache:false,
  success: function(html){
    $('#msg').html("success"); 
  }
});
return false;
  }

  </script>
```

PHP code: server.php

```
    $roomid = $_POST['roomid'];
    $checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
    $checkout = $_POST['checkout'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO reservation (room_id, checkin, checkout) values ('$roomid', '$checkin', '$checkout')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    echo "success!";
```

please help me out of this problem, tyia!

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean in cant repeat element ID's? yes I want to have multiple columns base on my data in `room_table`

Comment: also, please learn about sql injections and how to prevent it or you're doomed. use f12 + network(or whatever the tab is called in your browser) too see what the response from the browser is.

Comment: thankyou! @Jakumi i will read that sql injections. Jakumi can you help me out of this problem?

Comment: you output your form three times, however, the form elements (`<input>` elements) each have an id. an id has to be really unique for any page the browser is processing. instead, look at how to "serialize" the form to use in jquery (jquery has examples). then you should check (f12, network tab) if your query gets sent, and it contains the right data, and finally, check the response (when you click on the request, you see the response). finally add error_reporting (see php docs) and display errors, to see errors that might be swallowed at some point.

Comment: can you give me exact code of this? :( i didn't get it.

Comment: nope. I don't mean to be cruel, but you're making too big steps, apparently. learn the concepts. 1. Ids are unique. 2. how to debug ajax. 3. how to debug php. writing code for you is not the purpose of stackoverflow.

Comment: okay sorry for being demanding, I just wanted to fix this. Big thanks for that, and I will study in that sql injections etc. Thanks bro :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies within your while loop. Your printed elements will all have the same id's. When your function is looking for an id to get the value, it will always return the first that it finds, no matter how many instances there are of that id. So you're having conflicting id's. id's should always be unique.

What you could do to avoid this, is to declare a counter outside your while loop and increment it inside your while loop, then attach that onto your id. In that way, you will always have a unique id to parse along.

For instance:

```
<?php $count=0; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rooms)) { $count++;?>
   <div>
    <form >
            <img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" style="width: 20%;">
            <label>Check IN</label>
            <input type="date" name="text_checkin" id="text_checkin<?php echo $count; ?>">
            <br>
            <label>Check OUT</label>
            <input type="date" name="text_checkout" id="text_checkout<?php echo $count; ?>">
            <br>
            <label>Room ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="text_roomid" id="text_roomid<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return chk()">
            <br><br><br>
    </form>
    <p id="msg<?php echo $count; ?>"></p>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

However, you will then need to change your logic for how you fetch the data from each element, as you don't really know what their id's could end up being due to the incrementor. It's not static.

If you need any further help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin said there is the problem with the id's so you have to change the logic a little bit.

```php
$db = mysqli_connect('xxxxxx', 'xxxx', '', 'xxxx');
$rooms = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY id ASC;");

<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rooms)) { ?>
   <div>
    <form >
            <img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" style="width: 20%;">
            <label>Check IN</label>
            <input type="date" name="text_checkin" class="text_checkin">
            <br>
            <label>Check OUT</label>
            <input type="date" name="text_checkout" class="text_checkout">
            <br>
            <label>Room ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="text_roomid" class="text_roomid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return chk()">
            <br><br><br>
    </form>
    <p id="msg"></p>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Then you can get the values individually and pass them as array to the server.

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
function chk()
{

var roomidArr = $(".text_roomid");
var checkinArr = $(".text_checkin");
var checkoutArr = $(".text_checkout");

/*
  You can get value of each element as;

  for(var i = 0; i < roomidArr.length; i++){
    console.log($(roomidArr[i]).val());
}
*/
//var dataString = Apply your logic here as;
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "server.php",
  data:dataString,
  cache:false,
  success: function(html){
    $('#msg').html("success"); 
  }
});
return false;
  }

  </script>
```